# for loop syntax execution in C language

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

IN C what will be the actual execution when the for loop syntax is for `(initializer;incrementation;condition)`
eg:

```
for(i=1;i<100;i++)
{
    printf("%d",i);
}
```

Comment: Actually, the condition is the _second_ clause, not the third. So it's actually `for (init; test; update)`.

Answer (score 2):

It will be

```
 123456789...99
```

Unless your libc doesn't flush stdout on close. Or are you asking how it works, in which, case, It's equavalent to:

```
initializer;
while(condition){
   ...
   incrementation
}
```

or

```
i=1;
while(i<100){
    printf("%d", i);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: `fclose` is defined to flush, and I think `stdout` is closed/flushed on program termination.